# How to change Spacemacs' default font upon startup based on screen's resolution?

Tags: emacs, elisp, spacemacs

The title is pretty self-explanatory. I don't really know ELisp so this question may be trivial. Anyway I have the code below in my `.spacemacs` however it doesn't work:

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-init ()
  (when (eql x-display-pixel-width 2560)
    (setq-default dotspacemacs-default-font '("Source Code Pro"
                                              :size 13
                                              :weight normal
                                              :width normal
                                              :powerline-scale 1.1)))
 )
```

Any help as to how can I achieve such a behavior would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was apparently quite trivial ELisp mistake. A working answer is:

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-init ()
  (when (eql (x-display-pixel-width) 2560)
    (setq-default dotspacemacs-default-font '("Source Code Pro"
                                              :size 13
                                              :weight normal
                                              :width normal
                                              :powerline-scale 1.1)))
 )
```

Not sure if above is the idiomatic answer though.